# Application should request server every 5 mins

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an ImageView in my application and I am loading the image in the ImageView using an http link. I need to update/request the http link every 5 mins to see whether any changes have been made. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use timer for the same and can call that specific function every 5 minutes. [Check this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/14403-nstimer-examples.html).

Comment: Thank you ! I have done it, but i got a small doubt. I completed lik the following in the viewDidLoad,

NSTimer *currentTimer;
currentTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(theActionMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

And theActionMethod is like this 

- (void)theActionMethod  {
    
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://saypeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/apple-3d-logo-wallpaper.jpg"];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *_image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
_imageview.image=_image;
}

Comment: Am i doing in the right way ? My question is whether it will check that http link ? and whenever the timer calls the theActiveMethod , it will call NSURL and NSData , .. will that result in any memory problem ?

Comment: not getting you. you mean whether your code would work or not? easy way is to implement and check. If any problem occurs,tell me.

Comment: Its working . Thank you. I used NSTimer to call that particular method  for every 10 seconds. But when i try to use the WebView, it is not working.
1. I have my blog URL and I can display it in my WebView
2. Whenever I make some changes in my blog, it is not reflected in my App WebView ?

Comment: I need to admit that your responses are so fast . Thank you !

Comment: NSString *urlAddress = @"http://example.com/"; NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

This is the code i use to load the URL in the WebView, If i make any changes in my website, that is not reflected in my App( which contains WebView ). ???

Comment: Better you start a new post with the same query.